# How Do I Test Functionality in an Angular2 Observable?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I am trying to write a unit test for a login method on an authentication service in angular2. The issue I am facing is that Observable.subscribe is asynchronous and is not run in my test, therefore `localStorage.setItem` is never run. I have tried to make my code return a promise and use jasmine done but this doesn't seem to work either. How should I go about testing this function?

**Code from Authentication Service**

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

  const url = environment.apiUrl;

  this._http.post(`https://${url}/authenticate`, {username, password})
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
      data => localStorage.setItem('id_token', data.id_token),
      error => console.log(error)
    );
}
```

**Unit Test**

```
it('should set id_token', () => {
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockRespond(validResponse);
  });
  spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.returnValue(undefined);
  authService.login('admin', 'secret');
  expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('i am a token!');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provides a fakeasync utility for testing to resolve issues like this.

You just need to wrap your test in fakeasync, and then after any method that is async call tick() which will allow any async methods to complete before continuing

Import the following into your test

```
import { fakeAsync , tick} from '@angular/core/testing';
```

And modify your test as follows;

```
it('should set id_token', fakeasync(() => {
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
    connection.mockRespond(validResponse);
  });
  spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem').and.returnValue(undefined);
  authService.login('admin', 'secret');
  tick();
  expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith('i am a token!');
}));
```

https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync